Node Installation failure for versions 14.5.0 and 16.20.2 using NVM
I have been running into issues installing node versions 14.5.0 and 16.20.2 using nvm.
Attached are the logs of the same.
Any idea on the cause for install failure?
OS : macOs Sonama (M3 Pro)
Shell: zsh.
NVM version: 0.40.1
Error logs for nvm install 14.5.0
type here╰─❯ nvm install 14.5.0 --verbose
Downloading and installing node v14.5.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.5.0/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64/files/bin to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64/files/include to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/include: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64/files/lib to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/lib: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64/files/share to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/share: Directory not empty
Binary download failed, trying source.
Additional options while compiling: --verbose
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.5.0/node-v14.5.0.tar.xz...
######################################################################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
$>./configure --prefix=/Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0 --verbose<
./configure: line 7: exec: python: not found
nvm: install v14.5.0 failed!

For node 16.20.2 installation fails printing the same log message multiple times
Downloading and installing node v16.20.2...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...
######################################################################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-darwin-arm64/files/bin to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-darwin-arm64/files/include to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/include: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-darwin-arm64/files/lib to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib: Directory not empty
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.20.2-darwin-arm64/files/share to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/share: Directory not empty
Binary download failed, trying source.
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2.tar.xz...
-gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_mul.o.d.raw  -c
cc -o /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_nist.o ../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_nist.c '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_HW' '-DNDEBUG' '-DL_ENDIAN' '-DOPENSSL_PIC' '-DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ' '-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT' '-DSHA1_ASM' '-DSHA256_ASM' '-DSHA512_ASM' '-DKECCAK1600_ASM' '-DVPAES_ASM' '-DECP_NISTZ256_ASM' '-DPOLY1305_ASM' '-DOPENSSLDIR="/System/Library/OpenSSL/"' '-DENGINESDIR="/dev/null"' -I../deps/openssl/openssl -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/modes -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448 -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32 -I../deps/openssl/config -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2 -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_nist.o.d.raw -c
cc -o /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_prime.o ../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA_OVERRIDE' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_HW' '-DNDEBUG' '-DL_ENDIAN' '-DOPENSSL_PIC' '-DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ' '-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT' '-DSHA1_ASM' '-DSHA256_ASM' '-DSHA512_ASM' '-DKECCAK1600_ASM' '-DVPAES_ASM' '-DECP_NISTZ256_ASM' '-DPOLY1305_ASM' '-DOPENSSLDIR="/System/Library/OpenSSL/"' '-DENGINESDIR="/dev/null"' -I../deps/openssl/openssl -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/modes -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448 -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32 -I../deps/openssl/config -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2 -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_prime.o.d.raw -c
cc -o /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_print.o ../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_print.c '-DV8_DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA OVERRIDE' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_HW' '-DNDEBUG' '-DL_ENDIAN' '-DOPENSSL_PIC' '-DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ' '-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT' '-DSHA1_ASM' '-DSHA256_ASM' '-DSHA512_ASM' '-DKECCAK1600_ASM' '-DVPAES_ASM' '-DECP_NISTZ256_ASM' '-DPOLY1305_ASM' '-DOPENSSLDIR="/System/Library/OpenSSL/"' '-DENGINESDIR="/dev/null"' -I../deps/openssl/openssl -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/modes -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448 -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32 -I../deps/openssl/config -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2 -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_print.o.d.raw -c
cc -o /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_rand.o ../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_rand.c '-DV8_DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-DV8 IMMINENT DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER_DATA OVERRIDE' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_HW' '-DNDEBUG' '-DL_ENDIAN' '-DOPENSSL_PIC' '-DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ' '-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM MONT' '-DSHA1_ASM' '-DSHA256_ASM' '-DSHA512_ASM' '-DKECCAK1600_ASM' '-DVPAES_ASM' '-DECP_NISTZ256_ASM' '-DPOLY1305_ASM' '-DOPENSSLDIR="/System/Library/OpenSSL/"' '-DENGINESDIR="/dev/null"' -I../deps/openssl/openssl -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/modes -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448 -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32 -I../deps/openssl/config -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2 -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_rand.o.d.raw -c
cc -o /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_recp.o ../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_recp.c '-DV8 DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-DV8 IMMINENT DEPRECATION WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-DNODE_OPENSSL_CONF_NAME=nodejs_conf' '-DICU_NO_USER DATA OVERRIDE' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_HW' '-DNDEBUG' '-DL_ENDIAN' '-DOPENSSL_PIC' '-DOPENSSL_CPUID OBJ' '-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM MONT' '-DSHA1_ASM' '-DSHA256_ASM' '-DSHA512_ASM' '-DKECCAK1600_ASM' '-DVPAES_ASM' '-DECP_NISTZ256_ASM' '-DPOLY1305_ASM' '-DOPENSSLDIR="/System/Library/OpenSSL/"' '-DENGINESDIR="/dev/null"' -I../deps/openssl/openssl -I../deps/openssl/openssl/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/include -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/modes -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448 -I../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/ec/curve448/arch_32 -I../deps/openssl/config -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2 -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/include -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto -I../deps/openssl/config/archs/darwin64-arm64-cc/asm_avx2/crypto/include/internal -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.20.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/openssl/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bn/bn_recp.o

I've tried

Uninstalling and reinstalling nvm
Deleted nvm cache at ~/.nvm/.cache
The same setup works for nvm install 22.9.0 but not for 14.5.0 and 16.20.2


What's the output for python --version?

@Fares python --version  returns zsh: command not found: python , however python3 --version returns Python 3.9.6. I have checked and tried solutions shared at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2654 &  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/3284. Yet, running into the same error.

To resolve these errors, I deleted the files in /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions, which fixed the issue.
erred line:
mv: rename /Users/anonymous/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.5.0-darwin-x64/files/bin to /Users/anonymous/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin: Directory not empty

